# WebView: permanently disable status bar

Tags: android, webview, statusbar

I'm developing a one-view app which contains a fullscreen WebView. I started the project from a fullscreen template and added the code from both [this](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html) official docs pages.

When the app is first started it works good and i obtain a fullscreen with no status bar. Problem is that when i exit the app (either opening the task manager or pressing the button that leads to the home) and then re-enter in it, the status bar is displayed and there's no way to hide it back if not closing and re-opening the app.

How can i fix this?

---

**UPDATE**

Here's the source code:

- [AndroidManifest.xml](https://pastebin.com/hm93xm1z)
- [FullscreenWebView.java](https://pastebin.com/Sq7HiM7C)
- [activity_fullscreen_web_view.xml](https://pastebin.com/6bSMZqHt)

As already told, I haven't made much customization from the standard template of Android Studio.
The fullscreen code I've added is this, anyway:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions =  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_web_view);
```

Comment: Share the code you are using to obtain full screen. Have you tried to apply full screen code in `onResume() `?

Comment: where did you put your fullscreen code?

Comment: @JibяaᴎKhaᴎ just tried, nothing changes

Comment: @user1506104 in the onCreate

Comment: Can't get why people downvotes without give explaination. This is something really useless and frustrating!

Comment: please share your code block to achieve fullscreen

Comment: @user1506104 I've updated the question with the source code

Comment: @Mark can you show me your styles.xml?